# How do I log an object without having its toString() method called?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

How do I log all the properties of an object on the console? `console.log()` doesn't seem sufficient for some cases.

Take this example:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

console.log(Person);
console.log(Person.prototype);

var person = new Person('john');

console.log(person);
```

On Google Chrome, this will log:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
> Object
Person {name: "john"}
```

The first and third log will not show me all of the properties of the object. I can't expand (like I can in the second log) in order to see [[Prototype]] or any other property.

Comment: Try using `console.dir(Person)`, does that help you?

Comment: This is amazing! Now I can expand and see all properties. May I just ask you, why I don't see three times "Object" ; what is the first string I see? (before expanding)

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not understand your question, could you please add the code you see to a comment and i'll try to explain.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen You already answered the question, btw you should put an answer. But I wonder, additionally, why console.dir(Person); logs "> function Person(name)" and not "> Object". is it because of toString?

Comment: This is because "Person" is a prototype function, when you call the prototype function it creates and object. So that's why it logs "Function ...". Try calling `console.log(typeof Person)` and `console.log(typeof person)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.dir()` to view the prototype and all constructors

Answer (score 0):

declare the Class Object as below, below code is transpiled version of ES6 class

Class in ES6

```
class Person {
  name= null;
}
```

Transpiled code done via https://babeljs.io/repl/

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Person = function Person() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Person);

  this.name = null;
};

var p= new Person();
console.log(p);
p.name = "John";

console.log(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to understand that `prototype` properties are not same as `constructor` properties.

See the code :

```
function Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}
Person.length = 1; 
Person.aaaaq = 1; 
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person))
console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person))
Person.prototype.gender = "male";
console.log(Person);
console.log(Person.prototype);
var person = new Person('john');
console.log(person);
```

`prototype` properties can be considering as a template of an object, when `new` an object, all `prototype` properties will store into `__proto__`, when you try to access `gender`, it will look for `constructor` properties first, if didn't exist, it will go for `__proto__` to look up this property.

The final output will be :

```
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "aaaaq"]
Array[6]0: "length"1: "name"2: "arguments"3: "caller"4: "prototype"5: "aaaaq"length: 6__proto__: Array[0]
Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}
Object {gender: "male"}
Person {name: "john"}
```

Hope this will clear your confusions. 
Please check this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/jtwqgdvd/1/

Comment: Thank you ; "Person" is a function, which is an object. When logging, it displays "Person(name) {this.name = name; }". I wanted the ability to expand in console to see all properties. See comment of "Jonathan Nielsen". with console.dir() I can see everything. Sorry if question was unclear ; the question was not about difference between constructor, constructor's prototype property, etc.

Comment: Hi,  function is not an object in javascript.  function only will show the definition, only when you "new" a function, will return an object.

Comment: Everything that is not a primitive is an object. You even can add properties ; just try, console.log(Person.length); Try also console.dir(Person); and try to add any property key/value you want on the function itself => a function IS an object.

Comment: Person.foo = 'bar'; console.log(Person.foo);

Comment: ok, now i understand what you mean, you want to log all properties from Person ?

Comment: you can do this : console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person)), but function have build in properties check this : https://jsfiddle.net/jtwqgdvd/1/